# Como hacer una subconsulta dentro de otra en sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, postgresql

```
SELECT top 3 Pais, Continente, Max(Facturacion) as ValorMaximo
FROM Facturacion_Paises 
Group by Continente,Facturacion,Pais
order by Facturacion DESC;
```

Mi problema es  que tengo q Listar los tres países que más facturaron por continente (la respuesta ideal debería asumir
que la cantidad de Continentes puede ser variable)

mi tabla soloo tiene 3 campos; pais, continente(estos dos string) y facturacion el unico numerico
alguien podria ayudarme. Gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: solo tiene 3 campos la tabla pais, continente(estos dos string) y facturacion el unico numerico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar row_number para particionar por continente y ordenar de acuerdo a la cantidad facturada (en este caso de mayor a menor); remueve el top 3 y cámbialo por el where como en esta consulta:

```
select * from 
(
SELECT Pais, Continente, Max(Facturacion) as ValorMaximo
, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by continente order by facturacion desc) as rn
FROM Facturacion_Paises 
Group by Continente,Facturacion,Pais
) as f where rn < 4
```

Comment: Funciono!! que crack. Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Pues creo que sería algo así

```
Select top 3 continente, país, facturado from (
Select continente, país, Max(facturación) facturado from facturación_paises
Group by continente, pais
Order By 3 desc
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! esta me tiraba un error pero te agradezco la colaboración ya pude resolverlo :)